# Google API multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-api

I´m bit stuck. Why am I not pulling out latitude and longitude in my code?
I can´t see the flaw. Thank you in advance!

```
$json  = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Boston');
$result = json_decode($json, true);

$glat = $result->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$glong = $result->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};

print $glat.",".$glong;
```

Comment: The second argument (`true`) to the `json_decode()`-method tells it to return an associative array instead of an object. See @Templar's answer below... Just a note for future reference, there's no need to have curly braces around object properties. `$result->results` is the same thing as `$result->{'results'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the results as an object but it is an array, here is the fixed code:

```
    $json  = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Boston');
    $result = json_decode($json, true);

    $glat = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $glong = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```